# Creating mocks with BardJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, bardjs

I'm trying to create a mocked service using BardJS but I have found the docs a bit lacking and I'm new to JS unit testing anyway so its probably something obvious I'm missing but anyway... I have the following setup:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    bard.appModule('app.home');
    bard.inject('$controller', '$rootScope', 'HomeService', 'BreadcrumbService');

    homeService = bard.mockService(HomeService, {});
    breadcrumbService = bard.mockService(BreadcrumbService, {});

    homeController = $controller('HomeController');
    $rootScope.$apply();
});
```

When I try to expect that a method on the BreadcrumbService has been called I get the following error:

```
Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.
```

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: If you can provide your `expect()` call that is throwing the error that would be helpful. Also what version of bardjs you are using. Are you also including the sinon library to your test runner?

Comment: Did you fix this?  I am wondering how it worked.